# What is a Google App Engine instance?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to estimate the monthly costs for having GAE for in-app store and I do not really understand what is an instance and what can I do within one instance.

Can I just have one instance with multiple threads to deal with multiple clients? And as I have 28 hours of free instance per app per day (http://cloud.google.com/pricing/), does it mean that I would not pay for my server app running all the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An instance is an instance of a virtual server, running your code, that is able to serve requests to clients. This is usually done in parallel (Goroutines, Java threads, Python threads with 2.7) for most efficient usage of available resources.

Response times depends on what you're doing in your code, and it's usually IO dependent. If you have a waterfall of serial database lookups, it takes longer than if you only have a single multiget and perhaps an async write.

Part of the deal with GAE is that Google handles the elasticity for you. If there are a lot of connections waiting, new instances will start as needed (until your quota is exhausted). That means it can be difficult to estimate cost upfront, because you don't know exactly how efficient your code is and how much resources you'll need. I recommend a scheme where more usage means more income, and income per request is higher than cost per request. :)

You can tweak settings, saying you want requests to wait in queue, or always have a couple of spare instances ready to serve new requests, which will affect cost for you and response times for users.

In an IaaS scenario you could say that you will use five instances and that's the cost, but in reality you might need only 1 at night local time, and 25 the rest of the day, which means your users would most likely see dropped connections or otherwise have a negative user experience.

A free instance is normally able to handle test traffic during development without exhausting the quota.

Answer (score 0):

Well AppEngine may decide you need to have more than one instance running to handle the requests and so will start another one.  You won't be able to limit it to one running instance.  In fact, it's sometimes unclear why AE starts another instance when it seems like the requests are low, but it will if it decides it needs another warm instance to be ready to handle requests if the serving instance(s) are too near their limit.